# Dataframe converting to Option[DataFrame] after it's mapped

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to make a function that maps table names to Dataframes, my code is:

```
  def tableGen(tables: Array[Any], df: DataFrame, sqlContext: SQLContext): Map[String,DataFrame]={
    df.registerTempTable("TempTable")
    var myMap: Map[String,DataFrame] = Map()
    for(i <- tables){
      val queryRows = sqlContext.sql(s"SELECT * FROM TempTable WHERE table = '$i'")
      queryRows.cache()
      myMap += (i.toString -> queryRows.toDF())
    }
    for((k,v) <- myMap){
      printf("Key: %s , Value: %s\n",k,v)
    }
    myMap
  }
```

Although I explicitly state I want my return type to be Map[String,DataFrame] when I go outside of the function and do these:

```
val test: DataFrame = TableMap.get("Company")
test.show()
```

I get a type mismatch error:

```
Error:(41, 39) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame]
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    val test: DataFrame = TableMap.get("Company")
```

I don't even know what Option[org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] is, and I don't know why it converts.

Comment: What is this code really used for? Is it a big table which one column table?

Comment: It's used with maxwell, I have a giant json file filled with bin log info so it's a separation step.

Comment: I had similar case. just the column is different. Please check my answer if it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Although I explicitly state I want my return type to be Map[String,DataFrame] when I go outside of the function and do these:

Below I link to the docs of these classes.

[`Map[String,DataFrame]#get(String)`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@get(key:A):Option[B]) returns an `Option[DataFrame]`. An [`Option[T]`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.Option) is a type that can contain one of two values `Some[T]` or `None`, None indicates the absence of a value.

You can either do

```
TableMap.get("Company") map { test.show() }
```

To properly deal with Option or you just

```
val test: DataFrame = TableMap("Company")
test.show()
```

To bypass the Option ([Map#apply method](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map@apply(key:A):B)). This second one is not recommended because it will just throw a Exception.

Comment: Thanks! I got the second one to work, and then realized I could do tableMap.get("Company").get, I hope that's an okay option.

Comment: it's just like the second

Answer (score 1):

Based on certain category column, create a map based on this column. In this case the category column is `table`.

```
val categoryCol = col("table")

// category can be type String, Int, ...
val categories = df.select(categoryCol).distinct.collect.map(row => row.get(0))

// result is Map[String, DataFrame]
val dfs = categories.map {
    category => 
        (category.toString, df.filter(categoryCol === category).cache)
    }
    .toMap

val companyDF = dfs("Company")
```

Comment: This wasn't the problem I had, but you really cleaned up my code, thanks!